# Cartthrob - Compatibility issue between a discount & coupon code

Tags: cartthrob, discounts

Ok, I have a discount and a coupon code that aren't playing well together.

The **discount**...
* Free shipping for all Orders over $100 (fairly common offer)

[image]

... and a **Coupon Code**...
* 20% off a specific Product Category
[image]

**The issue**
When you purchase over $100 the shipping is removed (as per the Discount).  Unfortunately, when you add the Coupon Code the shipping is added back in.  I understand they should be able to work together.

Note - What does work together with the Coupon Code is the straight "Percentage Off" discount.

I would really appreciate any thoughts on how to fix this.

Comment: Does the application of the coupon bring the total below the discount threshold, by any chance?